# Problem in doing action on new window using Selenium Webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on Selenium with java, I open a driver change its proxy and do some actions, when I tried to switch to another window and change its proxy the actions don't happened, it showed this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null
```

if their is someone who has already worked with switching to windows and change proxy please help

I tried to use the method swith().to but I couldn't change the proxy so I tried to use another driver.

The code, First driver:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("http://" + proxyy);
proxy.setSslProxy("http://" + proxyy);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
randomSleep();
driver.get(JDD.url);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

---

Second driver:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("http://" + "104.227.100.66:8147");
proxy.setSslProxy("http://" + "104.227.100.66:8147");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
driver2 = new ChromeDriver(options);
randomSleep();
driver2.get(JDD.url);
driver2.manage().window().maximize();
profil("djfbadhz", "s9djq1ri28fz");
driver2.getWindowHandle();
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy("http://" + proxyy);
        proxy.setSslProxy("http://" + proxyy);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        randomSleep();
        driver.get(JDD.url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: and for the second driver

Comment: Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.setHttpProxy("http://" + "104.227.100.66:8147");
            proxy.setSslProxy("http://" + "104.227.100.66:8147");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
            driver2 = new ChromeDriver(options);
            randomSleep();
            driver2.get(JDD.url);
            driver2.manage().window().maximize();
            profil("djfbadhz", "s9djq1ri28fz");
            driver2.getWindowHandle();

Comment: I added your code to your original question. It might not be enough to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided reproducible code, I am just going to provide a simple example on how to switch tabs using Selenium 4 (and JUnit 5). If you are using Selenium 3, the way to do it is almost the same. I can provide an appropriate example if you require it.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotEquals;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ChromeTest {
    
    @Test
    void helloWorldTest () {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "F:/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String firstTabHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // save the first tab handle

        // Open a new tab in the same browser session
        WebDriver newTab = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
        newTab.get("https://www.msn.com/");
        String secondTabHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // save the new tab handle

        assertNotEquals(firstTabHandle, secondTabHandle); // not needed.. test the handles are different if you would like
        sleep(driver);
        driver.switchTo().window(firstTabHandle); // switch back to first tab
        sleep(driver);
        driver.switchTo().window(secondTabHandle); // switch back to new tab
        sleep(driver);
        driver.quit(); // end your browser session
    }
    
    private void sleep (WebDriver driver) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//body")));
    }
}
```

---

### Can a web driver gain access to a window controlled by another web driver?

To my knowledge, the only way to do this is by using a driver created from the same session. You cannot start two independent sessions and hand off control to the other driver (to the best of my knowledge).

When invoking `driver.switchTo().window(String windowHandle)`, a web driver is returned that has focus on the newly created window. HOWEVER, this is the same instance as the "driver" used to call `switchTo().window()`. Therefore, whether you used the returned driver or the original driver is immaterial, since they the same. Honestly, I don't know why this method returns an object at all. That said, when I ran this test using the returned driver, the test was more stable. When I used the same original instance, it tended to fail more for `NoSuchElement` during the second iteration. I know this could be fixed with the appropriate `WebDriverWait`, but I found this interesting.

To simulate the fact that this driver can interact with either window, I created the test below. The test passes three inputs to iterate over, and uses these strings to search on both Yahoo (original window) and Google (new window); all of which is done with the second (new) driver. This course of action is not necessary. Of course, each driver can interact with whichever window they created. However, in order to interact with a page, it needs to contain focus.

What does this mean related to using proxies? I do not know. All I know is that

1. A browser session can be interacted with by one and only one driver
2. Proxies (along with other options) are set before the session starts and cannot be changed after the session has begun.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ChromeTest {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeAll
    static void setup () {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "F:/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    static void teardown () {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
    
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"dog", "cat", "birds"})
    void simulateCodeTest (String input) {
        driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        String originalWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        WebDriver newWindowDriver = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
        newWindowDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
        String newWindowHandle = newWindowDriver.getWindowHandle();
        newWindowDriver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);
        assertTrue(originalWindow.equals(newWindowDriver.getWindowHandle()));
        
        newWindowDriver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
        WebElement searchField = new WebDriverWait(newWindowDriver,
            Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")));
        new Actions(newWindowDriver).sendKeys(searchField, input)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
        
        newWindowDriver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);
        searchField = new WebDriverWait(newWindowDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(5),
            Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='p']")));
        new Actions(newWindowDriver).sendKeys(searchField, input)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
        WebElement searchButton =
            newWindowDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
        searchButton.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to switch between windows not tabs and to change proxy also. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @kadourizakariae To switch windows, simply change `WindowType`. I don't believe "proxy" will affect the code. Have you tried this? Also, when you troubleshoot problems, you start by removing all unnecessary things. You can then integrate them later one by one. And since your code is incomplete and not reproducible, this is the best I can offer you.

Comment: @kadourizakariae If you try this and it works, you can modify your question and we could work on the proxy part.

Comment: how to change the proxy of the second window?

Comment: @kadourizakariae Did the rest of the code work?

Comment: Maybe you can provide me with both proxies if they are public. To be honest, I don't see an issue with proxies as the two are completely independent sessions. Any problem might be proxy related and not browser window related. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @kadourizakariae We can chat in LinkedIn if you would like. One thing I would like to bring to your attention just in case: if you are trying to use the `windowHandle` of one window to tell the driver controlling the other window to switch to it, this is impossible. Window handles are unique to a browser session. Therefore, the window handles for driver1 will not exist in the session controlled by driver2 and vice versa. In fact, I cannot see a valid use case where you would allow a second driver to take over a browser session controlled by another driver. Selenium was not designed that way.

Comment: @kadourizakariae I know this may not be the answer you were looking for, but if the correct answer for what _I think_ you are trying to do. Still, I would appreciate if you would select this as the best answer (by clicking the checkmark) once you are convinced what I am stating here is correct.